# How to make an auto-scrolling message box without forced reflow?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

My app has an output box comparable to a terminal emulator or message app. I want it to scroll to the bottom when new items appear.

Currently I'm doing the following (React + Tailwind):

```
const scrollRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({
    top: scrollRef.current.scrollHeight,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}, [items]);

//...

<div ref={scrollRef} className="overflow-auto">
{/* ... */}
</div>
```

When the number of items grows, adding an item becomes very slow. Chrome dev tools performance tool  highlights a forced reflow. React dev tools profiler shows most time spent in passive effects, which as I understand is `useEffect`.

Changing to modifying `scrollTop` or using `scrollIntoView` don't seem to help.

How do I achieve similar functionality in an efficient way?

Comment: additional findings: `behavior: "smooth"` looks bad when items appear quickly. The performance issue (with adding an item regardless of `behavior`) seems to depend more on the complexity of the items (in my case they are quite complex in HTML and CSS) than the count.

Comment: I recommend you to research about following concepts, `windowing`, `virtual scroll`. Then, select a library which provides them, like `react-virtualized`, `react-window`.

Comment: @het thank you, any recommended place for the research?